# LINQ - NHibernate: one list items contains all other list items

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, nhibernate, c#-4.0, fluent-nhibernate

I have this structure:

```
class Foo {
    IList<FooAttribute> Attributes { get; set; }
}

class FooAttribute {
    bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And I have objects like:

```
IQuerable<Foo> foos; // Database repository object .AsQuerable()
IList<FooAttribute> attrs;
```

I need to filter only those items of **foos** that have all attributes of **attrs** list. 
I tried this:

```
foos = foos.Where(foo =>
                  attrs.All(a =>
                      foo.Attributes.Any(at => at.Value == a)));
var filteredFoos = foos.ToList();
```

and i think it would work, but would be super slow and... it throws NotSupportedException...

By the way... I use ASP.NET MVC 3 and C# 4.0, so even the newest solutions are very welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what nhibernate version are you using? 2 or 3 specifically

Comment: NuGet packages show this:
NHibernate 3.2.0.4000, FluentNHibernate 1.3.0.717, so I think it is v3

Answer (score 1):

```
FooAttribute fooAttributeAlias=null;
Session.QueryOver<Foo>().Inner.JoinAlias(x=>x.Attributes,()=>fooAttributeAlias)
.WhereRestrictionOn(()=>fooAttributeAlias).IsNotEmpty
.List();
```

I did not understand the query that you have written. I am not sure if the above query does what you expect, see the generated sql and see if it is correct. 
Also what might help is the sql query that you expect to see which will give you the correct result.

Comment: Actualy, I was doing everything in the right way (just the query needed to be changed a bit), but the bottleneck was that NHibernate is using Lazy Loading by default and it was fetching ~100k queries to DB to get everything... Not the best idea. Now I inversed everything: I take all the attributes that user wants to filter by and they are mapped to all the listings that have them. This way I get all the listings that have all the selected attributes and using LINQ .Intersect() I get everything filtered. Thank you anyways.

Comment: can you then add the soln here then?

Comment: It is commercial project, so I cannot do that. Though I could create sln to represent my problem. I am not promising to do that in a day or two, but eventually it will be here. Remind me if I forget to do that in a week or two.